# LWC Data value too large: Error: Unable to save any logic to the component

Tags: lightning-web-components, limits, bug

Got error when saving / deploying the code to the Org.
The error message:

```
Source: data value too large: 
import { LightningElement, track, api, wire } from 'lwc'
import getAllApprovedQuotes from "@salesforce/apex/{!ID:@@@sfdc=01p8A000003qsBQ=sfdc@@@}.getAllApprovedQuotes"
import getSaveFilters from "@salesforce/apex/{!ID:@@@sfdc=01p8A000003qsBQ=sfdc@@@}.getSaveFilters"
import getSavedFilterData from "@salesforce/apex/{!ID:@@@sfdc=01p8A000003qsBQ=sfdc@@@}.getSavedFilterData"
import getQuotesWithFilter from "@salesforce/apex/{!ID:@@@sfdc=01p8A0000056tf7=sfdc@@@}.getQuotesWithFilter"
import getQuotesApproved from "@salesforce/apex/{!ID:@@@sfdc=01p8A000003qsBQ=sfdc@@@}.getQuotesApproved&"
import getQuotesSubmitForApproval from "@ (0:0)
```

Comment: How many lines of code you have in that component?

Comment: more than 3000 lines

Comment: Looks like you're trying to take in more information than you have allocated memory for. You will need to refactor your code to work in batches of information instead of the entire collection at once.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each source file is limited to 131kb (2^17 characters). You will need to make smaller components/files in order to deploy your component. Components should be small and reusable. Entire applications should not be coded into a single component.

Comment: usually const = []; declaration consume more characters any ways to break the const declaration in seperate components or files?

Comment: @Nirmal Include the structure in a secondary JS file, then import it: `import FIELDLIST from './fieldlist.js'; const FIELDS = FIELDLIST;` should work.

Comment: Thanks for the help , Temporarily i removed all unwanted code and comments and found some characters left . I managed to fix this. How to invoke elements inside FIELDLIST which is coming from another file. this keyword doesnt help. Sorry I am new to LWC.

Comment: thanks @sfdcfox, is there any documentation about this? and can this limitation be raised?

Comment: @Rival (a) I haven't seen it documented anywhere, and (b) I presume that the limitation is based on the underlying table, so it's not likely that it can be raised for an individual subscriber.

Comment: i see, how do you split the JS file other than using static resources? do you think have child blank LWC package (JS and HTML) and include it on the layout that contains all the JS helper method will work? @sfdcfox or is it possible to add only additional JS file under one LWC component so that we don't create another LWC package component?

Comment: @Rival You can indeed have multiple js files in a component package and import the methods via normal import statements. I'm actually designing some components right now that have that design, it works well.